# How can I limit content from an API to 15 words (not chars) using Angular 10+?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, frontend, backend

I want to limit some content(which it's 50+ words approx) from my API to 15 words , I am trying to make a Pipe but isn't work, the pipes I've found are limit but only characters not words..

I use this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'limitToPipe'
})
export class LimitToPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, limit: number): string {
    let trail = '...';

return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + trail : value;


 }

}
```

as I said before, that is not what I want, cause I need to return 15 words and not characters.

can someone help me to do this ? I'm wasted from morning to night trying to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, just noting that you need to decide exactly what a word is, like: are you including punctuation in your definition of a word; does a hyphenated word count as one or two words...

I haven't checked your code, but it looks like you have the pipe working so just need 15 words? I'd use a regex - something like this:

```
transform (value: string, words: number): string {
  const regex = new RegExp(`((\\W*\\w+){0,${words}})`);
  const result = value.match(regex)[1];
  return result.length < value.length ? result + '...' : result;
}
```

The regex is:

```
((\W*\w+){0,15}})
```

which matches 0 or more non-word characters '\W+', followed by 1 or more word characters '\w+', then looks for between 0 and 15 matches, taking as many as it can find (in case your initial string has less than 15 words).

If you want to be more specific about which characters to include than \W \w, you can switch them out for explicit character classes. e.g. to add a hyphen to the word characters (to make hyphenated words one word):

```
transform (value: string, words: number): string {
  const chars='-A-Za-z0-9_';
  const regex = new RegExp(`(([^${chars}]*[${chars}]+){0,${words}})`);
  const result = value.match(regex)[1];
  return result.length < value.length ? result + '...' : result;
}
```

Building a regex of:

```
(([^-A-Za-z0-9_]*[-A-Za-z0-9_]+){0,15}})
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you so much Barney, for your answer, this is so helpful for me, I didn't know much about regular expressions but this could bring me to learn more about it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the words by splitting them instead of substring. Please check the following code which split the words and returns only the limit specified,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    
@Pipe({
   name: 'limitWords'
})
export class LimitWordsPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: any, limit: any): any {
      return value.length > limit ? value.split(' ').slice(0,limit).join(' ') + '...' :value;
   }
}
```

App Url - https://limitwordspipe.stackblitz.io
Editor Url - https://stackblitz.com/edit/limitwordspipe?file=src/app/limit-words.pipe.ts

Comment: Watch out for double spaces which some people like after a full stop. `'The dog barked.  It was hungry.'` will split into `["The", "dog", "barked.", "", "It", "was", "hungry."]`, and you'll lose a word.

Comment: You may want to use a regex like `split(' +')` instead, which won't have this problem.

Comment: Thank you @Barney for spotting it and improving the answer even better.

Comment: thanks for your answer, for the time you spent answering this, It's so helpful for me.. I'll learn more about reg exp. 

cheers!!